# Calculate grand total of items

Tags: html, angular, sqlite, ionic-framework

By fetching data from my SQLite database I'm displaying a list of items using *ngFor. I'm able to show the name, amount, price and total of each item. How to get the grand total at the bottom of the list?

[example picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DjHXz.jpg).

.html code :

```
 <ion-grid>
  <ion-row nowrap class="headers">
    <ion-col size="5" class="single-border">
      Name
    </ion-col>
    <ion-col size="2" class="single-border">
      Price
    </ion-col>
    <ion-col size="3" class="single-border">
      Amount
    </ion-col>
    <ion-col size="3" class="single-border">
      Total
    </ion-col>
  </ion-row>

  <ion-row nowrap class="content" *ngFor="let prod of products | async">
    <ion-col size="5"> {{ prod.name }} </ion-col>
    <ion-col size="2"> {{ prod.price }} </ion-col>
    <ion-col size="3"> {{ prod.amount }} </ion-col>
    <ion-col size="3"> {{ prod.total }} </ion-col>
  </ion-row >
  <ion-row  nowrap class="headers">
    <ion-col size="5" class="top-border"  >
      <!-- Name -->
    </ion-col>
    <ion-col size="2"  class="top-border">
      <!-- price -->
    </ion-col>
    <ion-col size="3" class="top-border">
      grand amount total
    </ion-col>
    <ion-col size="3" class="top-border">
      grand total 
    </ion-col>
  </ion-row>
</ion-grid>
```

.ts file :

```
export class ReportPage implements OnInit {

products: Observable<any[]>;

product = {};

constructor(public db: DatabaseService) {}

 ngOnInit() {
  this.db.getDatabaseState().subscribe((rdy) => 
{
  if (rdy) {
    this.db.getDevs().subscribe((devs) => {
      this.developers = devs;
    });
    this.products = this.db.getProducts();
    this.db.normalProducts();
    this.db.repoProduct;
     }
   });
}

async showRepo(item_date: Date) {
  this.db.repoProduct(item_date).then((_) => {
    console.log(_);
    this.product = {};
  });
}
```

Database:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS product(
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    name TEXT,
    creatorId INTEGER,
    price INTEGER,
    amount INTEGER,
    total INTEGER NOT NULL
);
```

Comment: must be something like this ... SUM(price * amount) AS total_products_price ... and then u should be able to use total_products_price

Comment: you need to calculate grand total in the .ts file and just need to display by string interpolation -or- write method call in HTML and implement it in the .ts file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call the method from HTML. Look into [this StackBlitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic6-angular13-tn2pfx?file=src/app/app.component.ts) to understand how to get data from the observable array and also go through the concept of observables and subjects in Angular.

In .html file:

```
 <ion-col size="3" class="top-border">
      grand amount total
    </ion-col>
    <ion-col size="3" class="top-border">
      {{callingfunctionhere()}}
    </ion-col>
```

In .ts file:

```js
    callingfunctionhere() {
    let totalall = 0;
    // we need to subscribe to products because it is observable, then 
    //only we will get data
    this.products.subscribe((data) => {
      totalall = data.reduce((sum, current) => sum + current.total, 0);
    });
    return totalall;
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I followed the code and call it using string interpolation, but I didn't get the result. all it saying is "[object Object]". is there we could do something like Two-way Binding method to bind the total from the html to the .ts and back to the .html?

Comment: if you're getting `[object Object]` in UI then use JSON pipe to see the object, then you can fix it by yourself easily

Comment: Thanks for your time. I have seen the demo example, the products you have specified are in local array. But as I have mentioned it before I I'm fetching the data from an SQLite database. So Can we use **[(ngModel)]="products"** to get the data from the .html and use it in the .ts **callingfunctionhere(products)** method

Comment: That is not the point here... Actually you are using observable array and I'm using normal array... Will update answer by using observable array

Comment: I've seen your update and tried it. but It didn't work as the data from my backend was different. But your brilliant solution gave me an idea. I've set a **#getTotal** reference value in my template ** <ion-col #gTotal size="3"> {{ prod.total }} </ion-col>** so when I got the data, change it to **this.products = of(this.gTotal)** in the .ts file. and using your method **<ion-col size="3" class="top-border"> {{callingfunctionhere() | json}} </ion-col>** I've got a response like this **
{ "__zone_symbol__state": true, "__zone_symbol__value": 0ናቕፋ 145 }** so how can I now simplify the response

Comment: You need to search for your calculated amount in that json that showed in ui, mostly it will be in value key. I mean in your json you may have something like this - value: ****